# How can I get data from a VC which is hierarchical above the other

Tags: swift, uitableview

#### Explanation

In my app, there is the possibility to add members and to the members, which are displayed in a `tableView`. If the user selects a cell, he gets to a `transactionsVC`where all transactions of the user are displayed. The user can add new transactions to the member. I want to add the possibility, that a user can add a transaction to multiple members.

#### My idea

I want, that in the `View` where the user can add new transactions, that there is a way to get to a `tableView` where all members of the club are displayed.

#### Question

How can I display all members of the club?

I have this now:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let destination = segue.destination as? MultipleMemberTransactionsViewController
    else {
        return
    }
    destination.club = club
 }
```

I think that I have to put something other than `club` in the line:

```
destination.club = club
```

#### This is what I got from Club to Members

```swift
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "memberViewController") as! MemberViewController
            destinationVC = vc
            let selectedRow = self.tableViewClub.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

            vc.club = clubs[selectedRow!]
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you think is the right way to do it. You have to create a new property for your members in your destination view controller, like this:

```
var members: (the type of your choice here certainly an array or dictionary) ?
```

And then inside the prepare(for:sender:) function pass the members to the destination view controller like this:

```
destination.members = yourMembers
```

And then use the list of members to populate a table view.

Comment: Ok, how can I assign my members, which are in this club? I got this code, when I pass my data from the `clubVC`to the `memberVC` : added it to question.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign my members"? Can you elaborate a little bit more on what you want to do exactly?

Comment: I'm building an app, to make the bookkeeping of clubs. I got club -> members -> transaction. Now I want to add the possibility to add new transactions to multiple members at one time. The way I like to do this, is when the user is adding a new transaction, there is a button, which leads to a tableView where all members of this club are. Now I want to get this members to this tableView / ViewController.

Comment: If I understand you want to display the members in a table view after passing the list of members to your view controller ? I this is the case just use the protocol UITableViewDataSource and implement the functions to use your list of members to populate the table view. I am not sure that I still completely understand what you want to do and which tableview you are referring when writing "this tableView / ViewController".

Comment: Yeah I know how to build the tableView, but I don't know how to pass this members to the ViewController. With this tableView/ ViewController, I mean the part, where the user can select the members for the transaction.

Comment: If you want to get the associated member when the user select a cell you have to use the tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:) function from the UITableViewDelegate protocol and use the index path (yourListOfMembers[indexPath.row]) to find the member selected.

Comment: Yes I know this,  but how can I get this members, when the user already selected this in another vc, but now he isn't on this vc anymore. He already went through the membersVC and went to the transactionVC and from there he goes to the addTransactionVC, where he can click a button and then he should get to this members, so there is no tableView to select a club.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do. I have maybe not enough understanding of your project to help you or you are not clear enough.

Comment: @adrgronding Yeah, Im going to explain you my project. So On the first VC, there is a tableView, where all clubs of the user are, which he want to bookkeep. If a club is selected, there is a tableView with all members from this club. If you select a member, there is a tableView with all transactions of the member in the club. There is also the possibility, to add new transactions to THIS member. Now I want to add the possibility, that the user can add the transaction to multiple members at one time. The user he can select, are in a different tableView. The user gets to them by a button

Comment: My question now is, how I can get the members of the (in the beginning selected) club to this tableView.

Comment: I think that it looks more like a logic problem. I don't think it's a good approach that your user can select members in multiple table views. You should maybe try to rethink the problem and add a view just for this. For example with a table view that list all the users of a club and allows selection with a checkmark accessory on the cells. I don't know how your model is but getting all the users of a club should be something simple to do when you have your club.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much I‘m going to rethink about it.

Comment: No problem, I tried to help as much as I can. Good luck with your project!